# If a particle is undergoing a uniform circular motion, then how is its angular momentum conserved about its centre in its plane?

Tags: rotation

I didn't understand why is there no torque of the gravitational force of the particle?

Comment: The fact that the angular momentum is conserved is a consequence of the torque being zero.

Comment: What force is causing the object to move in a circle in your question? And how is the circle oriented? More information about the system is needed to fully answer this question. There are examples of uniform circular motion where gravity does exert a torque, and there are examples where it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The net force acting on the particle in a uniform circular motion is the centripetal force with constant magnitude which is in parallel to the radius vector. Now recall that torque is defined as the cross product between the radius vector $\mathbf r$ and the force $\mathbf F$,
$$\mathbf M = \mathbf r \times \mathbf F = \mathbf 0$$ since they are both parallel to each other. (For the magnitudes $M=rF\sin\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $r$ and $F$).

Comment: "The only force acting on the particle in a uniform circular motion is the centripetal force" this is not a true statement. Do you mean to say the net force?

Comment: @AaronStevens Which forces are also present?

Comment: You can have uniform circular motion without all the forces being centripetal forces. All you need for uniform circular motion is that the *net force* always points towards the center of the circle with a constant magnitude.

Comment: @AaronStevens But isn‘t this the centripetal force?

Comment: centripetal force does not come into play out of nowhere. it may be a combination of many forces.

Comment: A net centripetal force does not mean all forces are centripetal in the system. Just like how a $0$ net force does not mean all forces are $0$.

Comment: @physicsguy19 Yes, sure. I actually have meant this by centripetal force. Is it wrong to use it like this?

Comment: You just need to edit your answer to talk about the net force as discussed in our comments.

Comment: @AaronStevens Ok, I see your point. I have changed it.

Comment: Thanks. The real issue is with the question, since depending on the system gravity could be exerting a torque. More information from the OP is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The torque is given by $\tau=r\times F$ where the cross product is 0 if r is parallel to F. This is the case for a force that points directly towards the axis of rotation.